# Isolable activated esters: Other than N-Hydroxysuccinimidyl ester and Pentafluorophenyl ester?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Are there activated esters that undergo amide bond formation with an amino group in a mild and selective fashion, other than NHS ester and Pentafluorophenyl ester?
I am aware that there are [many reagents](https://www.peptide.com/resources/solid-phase-peptide-synthesis/coupling-reagents/) to activate carboxylic acids to generate the amide bond. However, to my knowledge, only NHS ester and pentafluorophenyl esters are able to be isolated and characterized. Would there be any other alternatives?

Comment: Hydroxybenzotriazole (HOBt) ester

Comment: @Waylander can it be isolated?

Comment: best not to, besides being reactive they are potentially explosive https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6259230/

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: It is a balancing act. If the activated ester is highly electrophilic it will not survive isolation. If it is not it, may not be reactive enough to form the amide. p-Nitrophenyl esters are isolable and fairly reactive to nucleophiles.

Comment: @Waylander Would p-Nitrophenyl, p-Chlorophenyl ester require base when reacting with amino groups?

Comment: The usual conditions use tertiary base. The phenol (pKa 7.1) is acidic enough to protonate your amine nucelophile and stop it acylating.  See this review for further reading  file:///C:/Users/marti/AppData/Local/Temp/2005-t-61-10827-852-tvorba-conh-vazby-jd.pdf

Comment: @Waylander Have you used pentafluoro'benzy'ester before? Would the reaction with an amino group selective and relatively rapid?

Comment: I have not and cannot find much literature on them except as GC/MS derivatisation agents. Chemistry is an experimental scince - try it.